# Correct way to wait for an event before returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, event-handling

I'm using a csv-parser npm module to read a csv file, process it, and then create a statistical model based on the data. The issue I'm having is that the other file that uses this isn't waiting for the model to finish before moving on, so it ends up trying to use values/methods that are not yet defined. Based on other posts, this is what I have:

```
   this.read = async function(){
        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        console.log("in mv read");
        fs.createReadStream("./assets/stats-csv.csv")
            .pipe(csv({
                mapValues: ({ header, index, value }) => this.toNumber(header, value)
            }))
            .on('data', (data) => this.process(data))

            .on('error', err => {
                reject(err);
            })
            .on('end', () => {
               this.model();
               console.log('finished mv model');
               resolve(true);
               });
        })

    }
```

And then the other file uses the method the following way:

```
    this.train_mv = async function(){
        console.log("in train mv wrapper")
        const success = await this.mvReg.read();
        return success;
        //console.log(success);
    }
```

I added the "success" bit just to see if returning and using a value from the promise would help, but it doesn't. The function just moves on and doesn't even go to the "return success" line. Am I missing something about async/await? Shouldn't the train_mv function pause and wait until the promise resolves? I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: *doesn't even go to the "return success" line* If it didn't go there, it had to be hanging out somewhere in `this.mvReg.read()` right? Can you debug further?

Comment: That's what is confusing me so much, when I debug it isn't getting hung in the function, it just moves on a skips the "return success" line and goes to the next line of execution which uses the mvReg which is then has undefined elements because read() never finished. The debugger goes into read(), does some of the code but exits before the "end" event, then comes out to the train-mv function and skips "return success" before the promise resolves. Hopefully that clarifies it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try adding try/catch in your `train_mv` function that wraps around `await this.mvReg.read();` ? I think the only reason it doesn't go to `return success` is because the Promise rejects with an error.